# Can I create a branch on a submodule that is accessible to users of the my project, without pushing to the submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Edit: The answer is to fork the repo, and make that the submodule.  So simple!

I've added a submodule to my project.  It's open source and completely out of my control.  I want to modify files in the submodule, so I created a local branch within it to track changes.
However, I can't push branches to the submodule.

How can I get my local submodule modifications to other users of my project, without pushing a branch to the submodule itself?  I've got two ideas in my head, neither of which are perfect.

First is to create another branch in my project that doesn't have the .gitsubmodules file.  When I switch to this branch, the submodule will appear as untracked files, and I can add+commit them.  This still allows me to fetch/update the submodule in the future, but it requires my repository to house the entirety of the submodule as well (which is far far larger than my project).

The second idea is to keep a folder that houses all the files I modified in the submodule.  Other users could checkout my project, init the submodule, create a local branch, and simply copy and paste this "modified files" folder into their local submodule.  This works and it doesn't require me to store the submodule itself, but it's going to be a huge pain to maintain.

What I'm basically looking for is a way to achieve #2 automatically through git.  Is such a thing possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A submodule is very little more than "use this additional Git repository, and by the way, check out this one specific commit in it". This makes the answer to "how do I let other people use commits in another Git repository without putting those commits in the other Git repository" pretty clear: you don't. (Consider forking the open source project.)

Comment: Forking is exactly what I was looking for!  I can make my forked repo the submodule, which would allow me to create branches and still be synced to the original!  

I've never forked something before so I didn't consider it an option, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to simply fork the open source repo, and use my fork instead of the original as the submodule.  Now I can push my branch upstream to my forked repo, and everything works exactly as I want it to!